# Do you think these are the same wheel for all intents and purposes?

Tags: wheels, rims

Trying to decide whether this is a legit replacement before I go out to buy this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Rims are functionally identical, cannot say anything about the rest of the wheel. Please provide specifications e.g. Hub details, spoke count (if that matter to you)

Comment: Both are the same in terms of hub (regular QR). Spoke count may be different but I will double-check.

Comment: And rim width too, that is an important factor in comparing rims as it affects the tire profile for a specific tire.  And add to that: tubeless compatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the question is about the whole wheel, not just the rim. The rim dimension is the same, so the same clincher tires with tubes do fit. Tubeless tire compatibility is a complex subject and can't be answered based on these photos. Spoke count and rim color aren't that important, but different colors or higher spoke count in front may look silly to some people.

The main issue is the hub. The axle needs to be the same (the comment mentions both are quick release, so this should work). Since these are disc brake wheels, the disc mount needs to match too or alternatively you need to replace the brake disc.

Answer (score 3):

Both rims are 622mm diameter, with an internal rim width of 19mm, according to the numbers on the label.  They will suit exactly the same widths of tyre.

Neither appear to have a brake track, so they must be used with disk brakes.

The only difference in the rims is that one is blue and one is black - this may matter to you or not.

We can't tell:

- Spoke count
- Depth of rim
- Tubeless capable or hooked rim for clinchers
- Valve hole
- Weight
- Build material
- Quality/trueness
- Spoke length needed

There's also no detail here about why you need a replacement rim.  If yours was damaged and you intend to rebuild your wheel on the existing hub, then you need the same spoke count and hopefully your spokes are the correct length.